# How to "optionalize" block-based UIView animations?

Tags: uiview, ios4, uiviewanimation, objective-c-blocks

My custom control has a method -setValue:animated:, which takes an `animated` flag.

Before iOS 4, I would have written the animation thus:

```
if (animated) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Foo"];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
}
// ... layout views ...
if (animated) {
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Now I wrote this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(animated ? 5.0 : 0.0) animations:^{
    // ... layout views ...
}];
```

*BUT:* this leads to some elements not animating!

I call this method more than just once (first time without, second time with animation), so the second time round the animation is cancelled, setting my new frame "hard" (without animation).

How to implement optional animation with the blocks approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define all of the changes you want to make in a block. You then either feed the block to `UIView animate...` if you want the changes animated, or execute it directly to make the changes without animation.

```
void (^myViewChanges)(void) = ^() {
    myView.alpha = 0.5;
    // other changes you want to make to animatable properties
};

if (animated) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:myViewChanges];
} else {
    myViewChanges();
}
```

Comment: Nice...but why doesn't Apple just do this for you when you pass in an animation duration of 0? (I know...probably nobody here can answer that. Just venting.)

Comment: @GregMaletic sort of. But since the system handles when the animation block is run, it may not always give desired results. I just came across a case where calling animateWithDuration:animations:completion: called the completion block too late. Storing the completion block and invoking it in the else clause (as above) fixed it for me.